# Sum of signed permutations of digits equals zero

Tags: number-theory, permutations, natural-numbers

After playing around with signed permutations lately, (as part of studying properties of antisymmetric tensors and wedge products which are not really related to what I want to ask about), I noticed that *apparently* for every integer with $3$ digits or more, the signed alternating sum of its digits permutations is equal to zero.

In order to avoid abusing notation, I'll first define $P_{\pi}(n)$ to be the signed and permuted version of an $N$ digits integer via a given permutation $\pi\in{S_N}$:

$$ P_{\pi}(n) = \text{sign}(\pi)\sum_{i=1}^N{n_i10^{\pi_{i}-1}}$$

Where $n_i$ is assumed to be the $i$'th digit, and I define $n_0$ to be the least significant digit, just to ensure that the original number $n$ maintains its original sign (This way, it is "hit" with the identity permutation).

With the above, I can more clearly restate the observation, that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $N\ge3$ digits:

$$\sum_{\pi\in{S_{N}}}{P_{\pi}(n)=0}$$

Where it is assumed $\pi$ ranges over all possible elements in $S_N$.

In case this is confusing, a concrete example follows:

$$123-132+312-321+231-213=0$$

My question is whether this is a known result, and if so where can I find more information about this property? BTW, I haven't proved this, so I should also ask whether this even holds true or not (although at this point I am rather convinced it is). It should be straightforward to prove via mathematical induction I think, although it may be more enlightening to see a more direct proof (I tried to write one, but those anti symmetrized sums get really cumbersome really quickly and I gave up for now :)).

Comment: In this case, it is clear that there are exactly two permutations which have a given integer in a given position, and since these differ by a transposition, they have opposite signs.  I would think this would generalize so long as the length is $>2$ (since exactly half of the elements of $S_{n-1}$ are even).

Comment: @lulu Are you referring to the example I gave? I'm not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: Just look at the units place.  They sum to $0$ since each digit gets counted exactly twice, with opposite signs.  In your specific example, you see each digit, $1,2,3$ appearing twice with opposite signs, for instance.

Comment: Fix digit positions, let us say $k,\ell \in \{1,2,\ldots,N\}$. The subset of $S_N$ of those permutations $\pi$ with $\pi(k) = \ell$ has order $(N-1)!$, and are in natural bijection with $S_{N-1}$. The number $(N-1)!$ is even iff $N \geq 3$. This explains why it 'always seems to be the case for $N\geq 3$'. In this case your $S_{N-1}$ decomposes as $A_{N-1} \sqcup \tau A_{N-1}$ ($\tau$ some transp.). Thus, if you evaluate the whole sum, you will always have an equal number of positive signs and an equal number of negative signs for a fixed place (and also for a fixed digit).

Comment: Thank you @MatyMangoo but I think I may be missing your main point: it is quite clear to me that the number of positive terms is equal to the number of negative terms. But are you suggesting that the equality of the sum to $0$ is a consequence of that? This I am not seeing clearly yet

Comment: Ah, I get it now. You mean to say that any digit position in the integer will appear an equal number of times with negative sign and with positive sign, so it follows trivially from that...

Comment: @ Amit, yes exactly!

Comment: Thank you, and I realize now @lulu was trying to explain the same thing as well, thank you both!

Comment: In your case $$123−132+312−321+231−213$$ I would see it rather as 
$$
(100 + 020 + 003) - (100 + 030 + 002) \pm ... .
$$

Comment: @MatyMangoo Yes that's very useful! :)

Comment: Let $S^{i,k}_n$ be the set of all permutations on $n$ elements that map $i$ to $k$. It is sufficient to show that $\sum_{\pi\in S_n^{i,k}} \operatorname{sgn}(\pi) = 0$ whenever $n\ge 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice observation! We have

\begin{align*}
\sum_{\pi\in{S_{N}}} \text{sign}(\pi)\sum_{i=1}^N{n_i10^{\pi_{i}-1}} &= \sum_{i=1}^N n_i \sum_{\pi\in{S_{N}}} \text{sign}(\pi){10^{\pi_{i}-1}}\\ &=
\sum_{i=1}^N n_i \sum_j 10^{j-1} \sum_{\pi\in{S_{N}| \pi(i) = j}} \text{sign}(\pi)
\end{align*}

Now note that every $\pi$ with $\pi(i) = j$ can be written as $\pi = (1j) \tau (1i)$ where $(1j)$ and $(1i)$ are cycles $1\mapsto j \mapsto 1$ and $1 \mapsto i \mapsto 1$, and $\tau(1) = 1$. Then we have $\text{sign}(\pi) = \text{sign}((1j))\text{sign}(\tau)\pi((1i)) (= \text{sign}(\tau)$ unless $j=1$ or $i = 1$.) Note that $\sum_{\tau \in S_n} \text{sign}(\tau) = 0$ since there are an equal number of even and odd permutations (unless $n = 1$). We can think of $\tau$ as a permutation of $2,3, \ldots N$ or $\tau \in S_{N-1}$. So for $N >2$ and any fixed $i,j$, we have

\begin{align*}
\sum_{\pi\in{S_{N}| \pi(i) = j}} \text{sign}(\pi) = \sum_{\tau\in{S_{N-1}| \pi(i) = j}} \text{sign}(1j)\text{sign}(1i) \text{sign}(\tau)\\
= \text{sign}(1j)\text{sign}(1i) \sum_{\tau\in{S_{N-1}| \pi(i) = j}}\text{sign}(\tau)=0.
\end{align*}

Note that there's nothing too special about taking digits of numbers here; you can extend this for sums of the form $n_1a_1 + \ldots + n_N a_N$ for $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_N$ arbitrary constants and $n_1, n_2, \ldots n_N$ permuted in all possible ways. In this particular case we take $a_1, a_2,\ldots,  a_N = 1, 10, \ldots, 10^{N-1}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think I nearly got it entirely, but am I correct that to fully finish this proof we need to consider the cases $j=1$ and then say that $\pi$ can be written as: $\tau(1i)$ and also the case $i=1$ where $\pi$ can be written as: $(1j)\tau$? I am a bit confused about how these cases are handled

Comment: @Amit Yes that's right. I was implicitly taking the convention that $(11)$ means the identity permutation. I should've made that more clear.

Answer (score 1):

With juxtaposition not meaning multiplication, here is the idea of a proof by induction.
$$\color{red}{abcd}-\color{red}{acbd}+cabd-cbad+bcad-bacd+\color{red}{abdc}-\color{red}{acdb}+cadb-cbda+bcda-badc+\color{red}{adbc}-\color{red}{adcb}+cdab-cdba+bdca-bdac+dabc-dacb+dcab-dcba+dbca-dbac$$

$= \color{red}{3000\times a-3000\times a+(bcd-cbd+bdc-cdb+dbc-dcb)}$
$+ \ 3000\times b-3000\times b+(cad-acd+cda-adc+dca-dac)$
$+ \ 3000\times c-3000\times c+(abd-bad+bda-bdc+dca-dac)$
$+ \ 3000\times d-3000\times d+(abc-acb+cab-cba+bca-bac)$

Answer (score 0):

You have an expression of the form

$$F(x_1, \ldots, x_n; y_1, \ldots y_n ) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n}  \epsilon(\sigma) \sum x_i y_{\sigma(i)}$$

It is alternating separately in $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, and $(y_1, \ldots, y_n)$.  So it has to be divisible by some products.... But the degree is $2$...

$\bf{Added}$ See what happens with sums
$$\sum_{\sigma \in S_n}  \epsilon(\sigma)\, (\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_{\sigma(i)})^d$$

$\bf{Added:}$ We have

$$\sum_{\sigma \in S_n}  \epsilon(\sigma)\, (\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_{\sigma(i)})^d = 0$$  for $0\le d < \binom{n}{2}$ and for $d = \binom{n}{2}$

$$\sum_{\sigma \in S_n}  \epsilon(\sigma)\, (\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_{\sigma(i)})^d = C_n \cdot V(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \cdot V(y_1, \ldots, y_n)$$ where $V(x_i)$ is the [Vandermonde polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_polynomial), and $C_n$ is the [multinomial coefficient](https://oeis.org/A022915)  $C_n= \frac{(1+2 + \cdot +n) !}{1! 2! \cdots n!}$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Is $\epsilon(\sigma)$ the sign of the permutation $\sigma$? By $x_iy_{\sigma(i)}$ do you mean just the "concatenated" digits?

Comment: @Amit: Hi, it's better to work with variables instead of powers of $10$ and digits. For instance, for $n=2$, get $(x_1 y_1 + x_2 y_2) - (x_1 y_2 + x_2 y_1) = (x_1 - x_2)(y_1-y_2)$.